# Why console.log() outputs in middleware are only visible on the server when entering page directly?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I tried to test if I can output something in the middleware only on certain processes. But if I use the following code - `process.server` seems always to work - also when I enter the route directly via browser. Other outputs are only visible when I change the route via router. I'm using Nuxt in the universal mode. What's happening there?

Actually I want to feed the store from localstorage user data and then redirect the user when this page is a guarded one. This could be only done from `process.client` where localStorage is defined. Can it be done with middleware at all? And also when entering the page directly?

middleware/test.vue

```
export default function (context) {
    if (process.server) {
        console.log('MIDDLEWARE SERVER')
    }
    if (!process.server) {
        console.log('MIDDLEWARE NON-SERVER')
    }
    if (process.client) {
        console.log('MIDDLEWARE CLIENT')
    }
    if (process.browser){
        console.log('MIDDLEWARE BROWSER')
    } 
}
```

pages/test.vue

```
<template>
  <h1>Some test Template</h1>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    middleware: ['test']
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

After digging deep into this I found an answer from a Nuxt team member. Obviously this is the intended default behavior of middleware in the universal mode to run on page refresh only on server. The documentation wasn't that clear about it.

The only way to get stored data in the page refresh scenario is to use cookies like this.

```
//middleware/auth.js

export default function(context) {
  context.store.dispatch("initAuth", context.req)
}
```

Then:

```
//store/index.js

actions: {
    initAuth(vuexContext, req) {
     if(req) {
         if (!req.headers.cookie) {
            return
         } 
        // go get the cookie ;)
     }
  }
}
```

Comment: > `The only way to get stored data in the page refresh scenario is to use cookies like this.`
You mean get browser stored data in server side?
Did you try `nuxtServerInit`? https://nuxtjs.org/guide/vuex-store#the-nuxtserverinit-action